# Workflow background thread - how to wait

Tags: c#, multithreading, unit-testing, mstest, workflow-foundation-4

I have a persistent workflow (runned by WorkflowApplication class) and I need to unit test correctness of runnung this workflow.

I am running workflow from unit test and all runs fine, except I receive error message in output window:

> System.AppDomainUnloadedException: Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain. This can happen if the test(s) started a thread but did not stop it. Make sure that all the threads started by the test(s) are stopped before completion.

I want to test results of workflow run after it was persisted and unloaded, so I use code like this:

```
AutoResetEvent waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
WorkflowApplication wfApp = new WorkflowApplication(workflowTypeInstance, inputs);
wfApp.Unloaded = delegate(WorkflowApplicationEventArgs e)
{   
    waitHandle.Set();
};
// ....
wfApp.Run();
waitHandle.WaitOne();
```

The problem is, that workflow application background thread does not terminate right after unload of workflow, but test method does. This causes the error message in output window.

Any idea / approach / point how to wait for background thread termination?

Comment: Which thread you're talking about? How does that thread goes cross appdomain boundary? This exception will not occur if thread doesn't cross the app domain boundary. So I guess the exception is not because of the thread you created, but because of the thread created by unit testing framework. Or you're creating multiple app domains yourself?

Comment: My code does not create any thread. Thread is created by Workflow Foundation - thread where workflow is executed. This thread remain active after workflow was persisted and unloaded for a while, but unit test unloads app domain when test method is finished and thus exception ocurs. If I add a little delay after workflow is unloaded (e.g. 1500 ms), exception does not appear.

Comment: I'm no good in WF app, but did you checked [Completed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.workflowapplication.completed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) callback, may be that can help.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Thank you for point, but Completed callback is called only when Workflow is completed. In my case, workflow is not completed, it is persisted on bookmark, and thus Completed callback is not raised.

Comment: Check [Microsoft.Activities.UnitTesting](https://wf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Microsoft.Activities.UnitTesting%20Overview&referringTitle=Home) project on CodePlex. In your particular case you might want to look to [How do I test an activity with bookmarks?](https://wf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20do%20I%20test%20an%20activity%20with%20bookmarks%3f&referringTitle=Microsoft.Activities.UnitTesting%20Overview) topic.

Comment: Its not easy to test workflows with bookmarks due to its asynchronous nature. That framework abstracts those aspects. Unfortunatly it seems Microsoft isn't submitting any improvements/changes/bugfixes. From its looks the project has stopped in time.

Comment: @Jota Thanks, I am aware of possibility to use Microsoft.Activities.UnitTesting. I was wondering if there is a way  to wait for termination of WorkflowApplication class thread pool threads. Maybe it is more general question - how to wait for all AppDomain spawned threads wihout knowing their handles - if it is even possible..

Comment: Its a bit ugly, but throw in a thread.sleep command after the WaitOne call. Persistence of a workflow instance takes a few milliseconds. I believe waiting 250 milliseconds should do the trick.

Comment: Why Unloaded and not http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.workflowapplication.completed(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Will Completed is called when workflow is finished (riches terminal state), but not on bookmark suspension and persistence..